Food for thought: Which person has truth in this discussion on capacity and AC?
I have stumbled upon interesting discussion in the commentary section regarding safety of electrical engineering in home environment.

person1: AC voltage 'flows' even through insulator, fact.
person2: Yes? How is it possible the current won't electrocute you
after you plug in the mixer into socket wall?
person1: Because of a low capacity between me and the conductor, however the
capacity between the ground and human standing on the insulator is
vastly higher.     If you are interested, have a look at the
capacitance / functioning of the capacitor.

Can you tell me who is right and why - please elaborate with scientific arguments.
I guess the first person is right. Similar situations would be a person standing under high voltage transmission lines, yes there would be increased electromagnetic radiation while standing, but still it would not electrocute, unless you touch the cable above (transmission line) while standing even on insulator laid on the ground. This way it would create large potential gap and the result would be you either transforming into carbon or having your heart arrested.
Am I right? Can you explain how potential diff (voltage) relates to capacity? Do these affect each other mutually (linearly, exponential dependence)?

Please estimate the capacitance of said mixer + chord to ground/air and calculate how much current would flow there at 50 or 60 Hz at any mains voltage. Compare that with how much current is needed though a human to hurt him/her.

the second person does not make a starement ... only the first person can be wrong or right

what about birds landing on power lines? ... or this https://youtu.be/9YmFHAFYwmY?si=1QqPxYskqdpIUOjr

Voltage doesn't "flow", so neither is making truthful statements.

"Electrocution is death or severe injury caused by electric shock from electric current passing through the body" ... not everything will cross the threshold for "electrocution", but you may still get energy coupled into your body, ranging from no sensation / awareness at all, to tingling, all the way through to "death or severe injury" and beyond.

@jstola sorry about that, yes, the 2nd person just argues/teases - not a statement; at the end of the video man crawls with one hand on 1 wire and the 2nd hand on the the 2nd wire, but he should not have touched lines simultaneously like that, is that metal Farraday jacket the only reason he's not dead while crawling like that? Also the maintenance operator mentions fear of electricity, heights and women and is married, I think it's the best he could ever get. The helicopter in video is a capacitor too, does it mean metal shield of helicopter works as conductor and pilot's in Farr. cage?

@Finbarr that 'flow' was intentional, that's why I used apostropes. However, I have translated it literally even though it's incorrect expression.

Note that the term is "capacitance"; "capacity" is not used in this form in English.

Re, "man crawls with one hand on 1 wire and the 2nd hand on the the 2nd wire." Both wires are part of the same conductor. They both are at the same potential. You can see the other two conductors (also with two wires each) in the background.

Re, "...pilot's in Farr. cage?" Yes. The AC electric field near those wires is so strong that just being near it with no shielding would cause dangerous current to flow inside your body. The electrically conducting suits that the lineman and the pilot wear allow those induced currents to flow around their bodies instead.

@SolomonSlow Thanks, yes, one YT comment mentioned that the same potential is on neighbouring wires, AFAIK the phase is 120 degrees apart. However, wires on the other site of transmission line have completely different potential.


person1: AC voltage 'flows' even through insulator, fact.

False, category error. Voltage doesn't flow, current flows. We could say that it's sort of true about insulators, if you are allowed to confuse the terms like voltage and current, as AC current can flow through an insulator. However, if you are confused between voltage and current, then anything else said about electricity should be ignored.

person2: Yes? How is it possible the current won't electrocute you after you plug in the mixer into socket wall?


person1: Because of a low capacity between me and the conductor,

True. The low capacity allows only a very small current to flow, too small to damage you, at least in the case of a 2-pin, non-earthed, mixer. If it's a 3-pin earthed mixer with a metal case, the case will intercept the capacitance from any live conductors to a user, routing the current to ground instead of you.

however the capacity between the ground and human standing on the insulator is vastly higher.

True, but irrelevant to the question. It reduces the AC potential the person has with respect to ground. Higher capacity to ground however actually means higher AC current flowing through the person from the capacitance to the mixer, so it has the opposite effect to what the speaker seems to be asserting.

I've follow up questions...I understand everything in other answers and adjunct comments, but for your answer: Why's there a low capacitance between human and the mixer's conductor? Capacitance depends on surface area and reversely on distance. Even if I hold conductor with bare hand while using mixer, is there a low surface area? Regarding last blockquote, can't get it at all. I always visualize dielectric/insulator between 2 wires=capacitance model example. What are the wires and what is the dielectric in that case? Explanation's missing on higher capacitance on the last blockquote.

@Tony_12652985 I'm sorry you don't get it. With hand-wavy diagrams adn questions, it can be difficult for different people to make the same assumptions and come to the same conclusions. The last block quote in my answer is directed at the lower capacitor in the capacitive divider from source, to human, to ground. Increase thst, and the potential of the human decreases, although the total current through the divider increases..
